# Page transition animation between views

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, view, transition, slide

I'm fairly new to iOS, and I'm experimenting with switching views. I have 2 views, each with a button to switch the page. So far I've only managed to use UIViewTransitionAnimation but it only has the Flip and Curl Animations.

Instead of flips and curls, I'm trying to make the pages slide between views either right to left or vice versa. I've been searching on google, forums and even the developer.apple.com about transitioning between pages but I still couldn't find what I'm looking for. I did find this CATransition class but there's just not enough examples of how to use it.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean. Try looking for UIScrollView tutorial, or look in cocoacontrols.com if it is a complex animation. http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/stackcordion

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain it but here's a video to demonstrate what I mean, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=644kJKm2l30&feature=related. In the video, when the user clicks on Mail, the view slides. I'm trying to do just that. Not sure what class to use. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since my last ios-experience, but it looks like the UINavigationController is what you're looking for.

Comment: Cheers for the reply. I'll see what I can do :)